# What is the difference between Flux.create() vs Flux.push() in project reactor?

Tags: project-reactor, reactor

What is the difference between Flux.create and Flux.push? I am looking--ideally with an example use case--to understand when I should use one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

As the documentation says:

- [create](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#create-java.util.function.Consumer-): Programmatically create a Flux with the capability of emitting multiple elements in a synchronous or asynchronous manner through the FluxSink API. This includes emitting elements from **multiple threads**.
- [push](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#push-java.util.function.Consumer-): Programmatically create a Flux with the capability of emitting multiple elements from a **single-threaded** producer through the FluxSink API.

They are useful if the case you want to adapt some other async external API and not worry about cancellation and backpressure (which is handled automatically by this to method).

Here an example:

```
@Test
void testCreateToWrapMultiThreadsAsyncExternalAPI() {
    SequenceCreator sequenceCreator = new SequenceCreator();
    int numberOfElements = 10000;

    StepVerifier.create(sequenceCreator.createNumberSequence(numberOfElements))
            .expectNextCount(numberOfElements)
            .verifyComplete();
}


@Slf4j
class SequenceCreator {

    public Flux<Integer> createNumberSequence(Integer elementsToEmit) {
        return Flux.create(sharedSink -> multiThreadSource(elementsToEmit, sharedSink));
    }

    void multiThreadSource(Integer elementsToEmit, FluxSink<Integer> sharedSink) {
        Thread producingThread1 = new Thread(() -> emitElements(sharedSink, elementsToEmit / 2), "Thread_1");
        Thread producingThread2 = new Thread(() -> emitElements(sharedSink, elementsToEmit / 2), "Thread_2");

        producingThread1.start(); // Start to emit elements
        producingThread2.start();

        try {
            producingThread1.join(); // Wait that thread finishes
            producingThread2.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        sharedSink.complete();
    }

    public void emitElements(FluxSink<Integer> sink, Integer count) {
        IntStream.range(1, count + 1).boxed().forEach(n -> {
            log.info("onNext {}", n);
            sink.next(n);
        });
    }
}
```

Here you have a source that emits in elements in parallel. The source is composed of 2 threads and each thread emit `numberOfElements / 2` elements that corresponds to 5000 elements emitted by Thread 1 and Thread 2 in this example. This source is wrapped with the `create` method and here we test that in total 10'000 elements are emitted. The test passed.

Now try to replace `create` with `push`. The test won't pass (if it is passing use a higher number for `numberOfElements`). That's because `push` expect that only one producing thread may invoke `next`, `complete` or `error` **at a time** since it won't manage the use on the FluxSink API in a concurrently way.

Hoping this toy example can help you to understand when to use one than another.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html

create()
Programmatically create a Flux with the capability of emitting multiple elements in a synchronous or asynchronous manner through the FluxSink API.

push()
Programmatically create a Flux with the capability of emitting multiple elements from a single-threaded producer through the FluxSink API.

With create() you can produce items from multiple threads. Use push() only if you do not intend to use multiple threads.

Comment: The question asks for an explanation with code examples. Simply copying & pasting things from `Flux` JavaDoc does not make a good answer.

Comment: I vote for this answer because there is nothing to show from code perspective. You just need to determine from your source if it is single-threaded or multi-. Then make a choice between `create()` or `push()`. I would say that `push()` is really optimized to work faster, with only downside that it is for a single thread. Otherwise - race condition. You definitely can find more in Docs: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#producing. Not sure what else we can explain here...

Comment: Heh, and to complete the trio off, I'm in between. There's not much more sensible that can be added to the answer, but I'd say it's still bad form to just copy / paste from the Javadocs without citing the source.